# My code doesn't actually insert into the database

Tags: python, sql, pgadmin-4

I don't run into any error messages anymore but when i refresh my database nothing is actually injected? using psycopg2 and pgadmin4

```
import psycopg2 as p

con = p.connect("dbname =Feedbacklamp user =postgres password= fillpw host=localhost port=5432")
cur = con.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO audiolevels(lokaalnummer,audiolevel,tijdstip) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
val = "100"
val1 = 100
val2 = "tijdstip"

cur.execute(sql,(val,val1,val2))
con.commit
cur.close
con.close
```

The values to be inserted into my pgadmin sql database

Comment: Call methods with `()`, e.g. `con.commit()`, `cur.close()`, `con.close()`.

Comment: Is `con.commit` a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`con.commit()` should be a function call I think is your problem. You are missing the parentheses which treats it as member access instead of a function call. This also goes for the other methods `cur.close() and con.close()`